# Calculate the constant angular acceleration if 3600 revolutions are made in two minutes starting from rest.

Tags: derivatives, rotations

I am currently working through Morris Klines "Calculus: An intuitive approach" and I am struggling with a particular question: Calculate the constant angular acceleration if 3600 revolutions are made in two minutes starting from rest.

I understand how to calculate derivatives by iteration, I don't want a simple answer but an explanation that may help for me to understand how to get the answer.

I know that distance along a rotation is =$R\theta$, and angluar velocity is =$R\theta'$ and angular rotation is $R\theta''$.

I've calculated the rotation in $rads/sec$ as 1.5 pi.

What do I need to consider to derive the correct answer (which is pi $rads/sec^2$)

Many thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to solve it if it were asking about linear acceleration? A car accelerates from a standstill (with constant acceleration), and after two minutes has traveled 3600 meters. What is its acceleration?

Comment: Consider the total **angle** made in the time. If the angular acceleration is constant $a$ (units is degrees per second squared), then
$$
\theta = \frac{1}{2}a t^2
$$

Comment: Contrast Matti P.'s comment with the Newtonian mechanics formula for distance (assuming constant acceleration) = $(V_0 \times t) + \left(\frac{1}{2}a \times t^2\right).$

Comment: Yes, I calculated the acceleration as 0.5. My difficulty is extrapolating the principle of iteration to this question, however both of your comments are useful and I am trying to understand it now. Thank you.

Comment: I have a problem, if $\theta=\frac{1}{2}ct^2$ Then $60\pi rad=\frac{1}{2}c1^2$ and I get $120\pi rad=c$. Could you please suggest what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

$3600$ revolutions in $2$ minutes is an average speed of $30$ revolutions per second, which is $60 \pi$ radians per second. Just as with constant linear acceleration, the final speed starting from rest will be twice the average speed - because

$\displaystyle \frac s t = \frac {\int v dt}{t} = \frac {\int at dt}{t} = \frac 1 2 at$

So the final speed is $120 \pi$ radians per second. If you divide this by the time ($120$ seconds) then you get the acceleration.

Comment: Thank you, I see firstly I miscalculated radians per second, and a nice explanation of what the final speed will be based on the average speed. Plus an easy way to get the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

$3600$ revs are made in $120$ seconds starting from rest.
Let the angular acceleration be $\alpha$ revs/second$^2$. In $t$ seconds the angular speed gained would be $= \alpha t$ revs/second. Also the angular distance covered during any interval $dt$ would be angular speed at that time multiplied with $dt$.
Hence integrating from $0$ to $120$ we get
Angular distance = $\int_0^{120} \alpha t dt = 3600$ revs.

$\implies \alpha = 0.5$ revs/ second$^2$